# HP Laser printer, prints started good, but have got "liney" over time with "rainbow effects" to the colours

Tags: printing, printer

Ive got a HP Color LaserJet MFP M281fdw printer.

The printer is c.3 months old and has printed c. 1500 pages colour pages.

When i first got the printer it had the pre-installed factory HP "trial" toner CMYK cartridges, the print quality was good.

Once i started finishing the trial toner cartridges the i began to replace them one by one with non OEM cartridges. The HP printer allows you to use the cartridges but gives you a warning that you are not using genuine HP cartridges.

The non OEM cartridges worked fine at first, with good print quality. But after a while i started to notice some lines, appearing in the printed images, similar to the sort of lines you would see in an image printed on a un-cleaned inkjet printer. At this stage about half the cartridges where trial cartridges and the other half non OEM.

The images seemed to keep getting liner, and now there is a rainbow pattern printed on the photos as well as the lines.

Ive tried calibrating the printer, and ive tried cleaning the printer, but to no avail.

Any ideas what i could do ?

Comment: Use proper toner… though you may be too late for that now.

Comment: @Tetsujin when you say "you may be too late for that now" is it not a question of swapping out the non OEM toner for OEM ? Or is the damage already done ?

Comment: You'll have to try it & see. It may only be the cheap cartridges if you're lucky, or it may be the drum unit. They only last 3 or 4 cartridges anyway.